# How to change dnsmasq port?

Tags: network-manager, dnsmasq

I am using port `53` for my vpn, and **I need to use port 53**. I changed the port of dnsmasq, connected openVPN,  and now request are `unable to resolve` errors.

```
sudo dnsmasq -p 5642
```

. Is there a way to change the port of dnsmasq w/o conflicts/errors?

Answer (score 3):

No. Every piece of DNS requester software expects to find the DNS service on port 53 of the nameserver. If it is not there then DNS will not work.

```
$ grep '\s53/' /etc/services 
domain          53/tcp                          # name-domain server
domain          53/udp
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually some unix distros allow you to specify the port for DNS in the /etc/resolv.conf nameservers entry but unfortunately Ubuntu isn't one of them. If it were possible you would specify the DNS port in /etc/network/interfaces along with the IP address of the nameserver — presumably a loopback address in your case.

There is an enhancement logged: [Please allow specification of port in resolv.conf](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14242)

My guess is that you will have move the port that your VPN is using. However, there is probably a good reason why the VPN is listening on the DNS port. You might want to check it out before trying to change it; you might be trying to do something that it already does for you.